# How to store and then print a 2d character/string array horizontally for 5 times?

Tags: c

I want to get 5 students' grades (`{"A+","A","A-"}` like that) in an array for 3 subjects. How do I get user inputs and print them horizontally line by line in a table? I have created code but it does not work.

```c
student[i]=row,  
subject[j]=colomn

while(j<5){
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%3s",name[i]);
    }
}
// dispaying strings
printf("\nEntered names are:\n");
while(j<3){
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        puts(name[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What does "does not work" mean? Please provide a detailles description of failure. Please edit your question to include sample input together with expected output and the output you get. Also please edit your code to be a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not just a snippet without context that does not compile.

Comment: I've written an answer below.  In the future please provide a description of what is failing, and also make sure the provided example compiles.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will follow the instructions when I ask questions again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.  Make a struct that represents an "entry" of a database.  Each entry contains a student name, and an array of grades depending on how many subjects they're taking.

When you're using `scanf()` for strings, you'll want to scan for one less than the length of the array, in order to leave space for a null terminator.

You'll also need to flush stdin after each `scanf()` in case the user enters more than they're supposed to.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_STUDS 3
#define NUM_SUBJS 2

struct entry {
    char name[10];
    char grade[NUM_SUBJS][3];
};

struct entry entries[NUM_STUDS];

int main(void) {
    int i, j, c;

    /* Collect student names */
    for(i=0; i<NUM_STUDS; i++) {
        printf("Enter student name %d/%d: ", i+1, NUM_STUDS);
        scanf("%9s", entries[i].name);
        while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF); /* Flush stdin */
    }

    /* Collect grades */
    for(i=0; i<NUM_STUDS; i++) {
        printf("Enter %d grades for %s: ", NUM_SUBJS, entries[i].name);
        for(j=0; j<NUM_SUBJS; j++) {
            scanf("%2s", entries[i].grade[j]);
            while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF); /* Flush stdin */
        }
    }

    /* Print out table of results */
    printf("Results:\n");
    for(i=0; i<NUM_STUDS; i++) {
        printf("%-10s: ", entries[i].name);
        for(j=0; j<NUM_SUBJS; j++) {
            printf("%-3s", entries[i].grade[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample input/output:

```
Enter student name 1/3: Bob
Enter student name 2/3: Alice
Enter student name 3/3: Joe
Enter 2 grades for Bob: B+
A
Enter 2 grades for Alice: A-
C
Enter 2 grades for Joe: D- 
E
Results:
Bob       : B+ A  
Alice     : A- C  
Joe       : D- E
```